# Python function returning nothing when called

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def my_test(some_function):

    def wrapper():

        num = 10

        if num == 10:
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("No")

        some_function()

        print("Something is happening after some_function() is called")

    return wrapper


def just_some_function():
    print("Filler text")

my_test(just_some_function)
```

When I run this script, it should display:

> Yes
>
> Filler text
>
> Something is happening after some_function() is called

since `my_test(just_some_function)` calls `my_test`, goes through the wrapper function, checks if `num == 10`, prints "Yes," then goes to `just_some_function()` (since `some_function` is the "variable" for the function `my_test()`), prints "Filler text," then finally ends by printing "Something is happening after some_function() is called." But nothing happens in the console when I run the script.

Comment: yeah but you should `return wrapper()` or call the result like `my_test(just_some_function)()`

Comment: Looks like you're thinking about decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_test` is a higher-order function; all it does is return another function, in this case `wrapper`. You need to actually call that returned function:

```
my_test(just_some_function)()
```

Note, other than for demonstration purposes - or as a decorator - this is a pretty pointless way to write code.